# При пуше на гитхаб файл записывается в одну строку

Tags: git, pycharm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую Pycharm, VCS -> PUSH -> мой репозиторий.

Если делать пуш, происходит вывод только в одну строку.
Скажите, пожалуйста, почему так выходит?

Comment: Написано, что 27 строк.

Comment: Написано-то оно написано, но вы сами видите, что отображается. Вместо переноса строк там подсвечивается *^M*

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000554939-Intellij-adding-M-newline-characters